# How to shift object at index to last of an array , also change the colour of cell of the same in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to shift the cell of tableview in swift to last position and change it's background colour after selection of the same cell.

Comment: you can try using UITableViewDelegates ?

Comment: Use `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` and `didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath` delegate methods to swap table cells.

Comment: Can you please post any example of the same ?

Answer (score 0):

use the swap function to `swap()` the two indexes then use `table.reloadData()`, and use an index variable set it to the last index and in `cellForRow` method change `cell.backgroundColor` in case `indexPath.row == that index`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let clickedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    //Change cell with the last cell.
}
```

Hope this will help. You dont need to reload the entire tableviewcontroller.